# Custom Tableview cell messed up since Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I developed an app listing the videos from a persons youtube account.  A tableview was used with a custom cell to display a thumbnail of the video with labels on top of the imageview to show the title, how long ago posted and views.  This app has worked well before installing Xcode 6.

When I run the same app with no changes in Xcode 6, the tableview cells mess up and the imageview seems to expand and cover the title label even though the label is on top of the image view, and throw the other labels out of place.

See screenshots at http://lavabuild.blogspot.co.uk

Anyone any ideas why Xcode 6 is messing this up when it ran perfectly in Xcode 5?

Comment: probably the auto-layout has not been set properly. the iOS8 is more sensitive to get the correct setup of constraint than iOS7 was.

Comment: AutoLayout is not being used.  Would that cause an image to expand?

Comment: in that case the auto-resize mask is incorrect, but if you say that it is not used either... then you have found the problem's source. either the auto-layout or auto-resize mass has to be set properly, otherwise the UI collapses.